# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of null

Tags: javascript

here is the input file:

```
 <input type="file" class="form-control" id="tab3_fileAddproof" name="tab3_fileAddproof" autocomplete="off">
```

here is the javascript:

```
 $("#tab3_fileAddproof", r).change(function (e) {
                debugger
                var formData = new FormData();                   

                var file = document.getElementById(e.id).files[0];
                formData.append("FileUpload", file);
```

the error is on var file.

Comment: Simple: the id of the event (`e.id`) has nothing to do with the id of the element.

Comment: where should i change

Comment: on file change here i save the file by using ajax and javascript

Comment: How do i find the file name and details of the file usaing javascript

Comment: (sorry, removed comment that was too much of a rant (and wrong)). Please still clean up a bit: what is this `debugger` statement in the middle of your code?

Comment: @HuguesMoreau if you don't know the answer... then don't make any statement here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `event` object has a `target` property that is the element that caused it to fire.

```
var clicked = e.target;
var file = clicked.files[0];
```

There are a few ways the above can fail - if the changed element is not a file input and if it is empty.